# Laravel + MongoDB + Elasticsearch, configuration issues with Elasticquent

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, elasticsearch

I am building a web application using Laravel, ElasticSearch and MongoDB. To do so, I am using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb to connect Laravel and MongoDB (which works perfectly) and https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent to connect to Elasticsearch (which I am having issues with).

My model looks like this:

```
namespace App;

use Moloquent;
use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;

class Article extends Moloquent
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;
    protected $collection = 'Articles';
}
```

My controller search function looks like this:

```
public function search()
{
    $texte = $_GET['texte'];
    $articles = Article::where('Title', 'regexp', "/$texte/")->get();
    //$articles = Article::search('bu');
    //dd($articles);
    return view('pages.articles', compact('articles'));
}
```

When using the where function from the Article model I get this, that is 3 results

```
ElasticquentCollection {#134 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Article {#142 ▶}
    1 => Article {#143 ▶}
    2 => Article {#144 ▶}
  ]
}
```

When using the search function I get something like this, no results

```
ElasticquentResultCollection {#156 ▼
  #took: 1
  #timed_out: false
  #shards: array:3 [▶]
  #hits: array:3 [▶]
  #aggregations: []
  #instance: Article {#161 ▶}
  #items: []
}
```

Would someone have had to deal with the same kind of architecture and could help me out with that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `$articles = Article::search('bu')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$articles = Article::search('bu');
```

to

```
$articles = Article::search('bu')->get();
```

You are not fetching the collection. You have to use either `get()` or `first()` to collect your searched items.

Comment: When using get I have this error `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(),`. Something is up. Thanks